# Pagination in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, pagination

I'm new to selenium and following a small [tutorial](https://medium.com/@jidhiya_6779/web-scraping-using-selenium-and-java-6ef126bec672) on scraping that scrapes jobs from indeed.com, but I am having issues as it seems some of the elements have been renamed since the tutorial was written. I'm stuck on this part:

```
List<WebElement> pagination = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@class='pagination-
list']/li"));
int pgSize = pagination.size();
for (int j = 1; j < pgSize; j++) {
Thread.sleep(1000);
WebElement pagei = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//ul[@class='pagination-list']/li)[" + j + "]"));
pagei.click();
```

The xpath needs to be updated as the element can no longer be found. I have changed the xpath to this, but the list does not get populated:

```
//nav[@aria-label='pagination']
```

When I do this, it prints zero which means no elements have been added to the list:

```
List<WebElement> pagination = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//nav[@aria-label='pagination']"));
    int size = pagination.size();
    System.out.println(size);
```

Is this the correct xpath? I'm not certain as to what is supposed to get populated into the list of Webelements? Should they be page numbers?

Comment: please share the link to the page you are testing and any credentials that might be required to view the list. Also the error message and screenshot of the web element would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

You could try this path `//nav[@role='navigation']/div` This would give you 6 elements. 5 for the pages and 1 for the next button

[image]

If this is not the correct page, please share the URL and the element, I will try to provide a solution.

Answer (score 0):

The website [indeed.com](https://www.indeed.com/) have changed since the article [Web Scraping using selenium and Java](https://medium.com/@jidhiya_6779/web-scraping-using-selenium-and-java-6ef126bec672) was written. The pagination elements have changed. Currently the pagination is implemented through:

```html
<nav role="navigation" aria-label="pagination" class="css-jbuxu0 ecydgvn0">
    <div class="css-tvvxwd ecydgvn1">
        <button data-testid="pagination-page-current" class="css-1cpyzlr e8ju0x51">1</button>
    </div>
    <div class="css-tvvxwd ecydgvn1">
        <a data-testid="pagination-page-2" rel="nofollow" aria-label="2" href="/jobs?q=Api+Testing&amp;l=Pune&amp;start=10" class="css-e9oyys e8ju0x50">2</a>
    </div>
    <div class="css-tvvxwd ecydgvn1">
        <a data-testid="pagination-page-3" rel="nofollow" aria-label="3" href="/jobs?q=Api+Testing&amp;l=Pune&amp;start=20" class="css-e9oyys e8ju0x50">3</a>
    </div>
    <div class="css-tvvxwd ecydgvn1">
        <a data-testid="pagination-page-4" rel="nofollow" aria-label="4" href="/jobs?q=Api+Testing&amp;l=Pune&amp;start=30" class="css-e9oyys e8ju0x50">4</a>
    </div>
    <div class="css-tvvxwd ecydgvn1">
        <a data-testid="pagination-page-5" rel="nofollow" aria-label="5" href="/jobs?q=Api+Testing&amp;l=Pune&amp;start=40" class="css-e9oyys e8ju0x50">5</a>
    </div>
    <div class="css-tvvxwd ecydgvn1">
        <a data-testid="pagination-page-next" rel="nofollow" aria-label="Next Page" href="/jobs?q=Api+Testing&amp;l=Pune&amp;start=10" class="css-cy0uue e8ju0x50">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" focusable="false" role="img" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true" class="css-1xqhio eac13zx0">
                <path d="M9.888 5.998a.506.506 0 00-.716-.008l-.707.707a.506.506 0 00.01.716L13.06 12l-4.587 4.587c-.2.2-.204.521-.009.716l.707.707a.507.507 0 00.717-.009l5.647-5.648c.1-.1.148-.233.144-.366a.492.492 0 00-.144-.34v-.001a.611.611 0 00-.009-.009L9.888 5.998z">
                </path>
            </svg>
        </a>
    </div>
</nav>
```

---

### Solution

Instead of creating a list of the pagination elements, as the pagination keeps on increasing as you move forward you can use the following solution:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe");
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
driver.get("https://in.indeed.com/");
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(5));
// Create a Scanner object to prompt for user input
Scanner myObj = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("What jobs are you looking for ? ");
String job = myObj.nextLine();
System.out.println("Which city are you looking for ? ");
String city = myObj.nextLine();
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("input#text-input-what"))).sendKeys(job);
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input#text-input-where")).sendKeys(city + Keys.RETURN);
for (int j=1; j<6; j++)
{
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@data-testid='pagination-page-current']//following::div[1]/a[@data-testid]")).click();
    Thread.sleep(15000);
}
```

Note:

- Here `6` is the number of (pages-1) you want to scrape.
- `Thread.sleep(15000)` is to provide the window to pulate *Email Address* after the first click on pagination item.

Comment: Thanks for this. There was an error:                      org.openqa.selenium.ElementClickInterceptedException: element click intercepted: Element <a data-testid="pagination-page-..." rel="nofollow" aria-label="2" href="/jobs?q=retail&amp;l=london&amp;start=10" class="css-e9oyys e8ju0x50">2</a> is not clickable at point (287, 544). Other element would receive the click: <div class="ot-sdk-row">...</div>        Do you know what is causing this?

Comment: @fdama Can't comment further without the finer details. Provided the binaries are up-to-date the execution should have been seamless as in my win10 system.